# Htaccess Rewriting part of url

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this adress :

> localhost/wattathome/view?slug=multiples-services

And I would like to rewrite it like that :

> localhost/wattathome/view/multiples-services

or even better :

> localhost/wattathome/multiples-services

But everything I try with Rewriterule ends up with a 404 error.

Please help me D:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `localhost/wattathome/view` resolve to? Why is this not `localhost/wattathome/view.php`?

Comment: post what you have tried so far

Comment: @Halcyon I have another rule to delete php extension

Comment: @andrew 
RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ view.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ view.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
(with and without .php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understnad correctly your code

```
RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ view.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

will get view?slug=multiples-services and rewrite it to 
localhost/wattathome/view/multiples-services/ (note the end slash)

Try removing the ending slash and see what will happen

**EDIT 1**
Ok les try this one (remember, view.php must be in root folder):

```
RewriteRule ^view/([^/]+)$ view.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
```

Make sure that you have all your redirection rules above any rewrite rule.
So, your htaccess should look like:
- options
- redirections
- rewritting